# Firebase Mailchimp Extension - Update Subscriber Name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, mailchimp

Is there a way to update the subscriber when the user updates their profile with their first/last name?  Could that be done with a cloud function if not through the extension?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [can this be done] when the user updates their profile with their first/last name

There is currently no Cloud Functions trigger for Firebase Authentication profile updates. This means that there is no way to do this directly with Cloud Functions, and hence also not in the [Auth Mailchimp sync Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/auth-mailchimp-sync), which is based on Cloud Functions functionality.

If you build this functionality yourself (you can use the [existing extension source code for inspiration](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/auth-mailchimp-sync)), you can trigger an update of the Mailchimp audience directly from your client-side code when you also call the Firebase Authentication API to update the profile.